# new Date() not working in ie when comparing with different dates

Tags: javascript, date

new Date() is not working IE when Comparing two dates

```js
new Date("January2018") >= new Date("January2018") == true
```

this is working fine when i am using it in google chrome but when i use the same code in ie it results false.can anyone help me

Comment: It returns *false* for me since it resolves to `NaN >= NaN`. Maybe a different result in other hosts.

Comment: then how to make new Date() work in ie

Comment: See [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).